# How to read csv which is splitted into multiple files in pyspark with scattered contents?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have multiple csv files in order like 
a1.csv
a2.csv
a3.csv

the contents in files are splitted.
For example:
a1:

```
1,8767687,ERS
2,8798089,CTP
3,9879879,POI
4,987
```

a2

```
9878,RSP
5,9878987,CTP
6,9887987,CNR
7,8789799,PO
```

a3

```
L
8,9879879,LOR
9,8979879,IIO
10,876998,IYK
```

Now I want to read all these files and create a single csv file with 10 records.
If the line is splitted then it doesn't contains line feed character, so when I tried to concatenate all files using unix and then reading it through spark it works fine.

But I don't want to use unix command.

If you can help me reading these files using low level rdd api that also works. BUt can't figure it right now.

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to append files in scala , spark or pyspark ?

Comment: pyspark preffered, but spark-scala solution also works

Comment: u r using newlines in the field? Seems a little pointless this approach

Comment: These files are generated by an API and because of the size limit the data is scattered across multiple files..need help in parsing these as a single df

Comment: Could provide the desired output @Shubham? It would be really useful